# ¿Cómo puedo tener una variable que me vaya contando cada vez que llamo el mismo Activity en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de tener una variable que me vaya contando y sumando en uno cada vez que ejecuto el mismo Activity. 
Es decir, al iniciar mi aplicación yo me encuentro en mi MainActivity.java, luego mediante un Intent me gustaría volver a llamar al mismo Activity y poder "Contar" a través de una variable cuantas veces se llamo a ese Activity. Para ser mas claro, acá muestro un ejemplo:

**En mi clase Java**

```
// import
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
int cont=0
Intent i;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pregunta1);
        i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
......// Codigo de mi aplicación
        cont = cont + 1 // La primera vez que se ejecute, cont=1
        startActivity(i);
}
```

Luego al ejecutar por segunda vez mi Activity, mi variable cont tendría que ser igual a 2.
¿Existe alguna forma de poder realizar esto? Gracias.
Pd: La solución que estoy buscando es que todo mi código se encuentre dentro del mismo Activity, y no quiero que la solución sea pasar de un Activity a otro.

Comment: Además de definir tu variable como static es importante la guardes si es que deseas siempre se mantenga el valor aún estando en segundo plano (background), agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes hacerlo con una propiedad estática, por ejemplo, en tu MainActivity podrías declararla así:

```
public static int Opened;
```

Y luego incrementarlo así

```
MainActivity.Opened++;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Puedes realizarlo definiendo la variable que usaras como contador de tipo `static`**,

```
private static int cont = 0;
```

y el incremento puedes realizarlo mediante:

```
cont = cont + 1;
```

o mediante:

```
cont = cont++;
```

Ejemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private static int cont=0; 
private Intent i;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pregunta1);
        i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        ...
        cont = cont + 1;
        startActivity(i);
}
```

**Pero hay algo importante a contemplar, si deseas que este valor persista una opción es guardar este valor en preferencias ya que puedes enviar a segundo plano tu aplicación y el valor de `cont` puede reiniciarse debido a que el sistema operativo puede requerir memoria para otras aplicaciones o procesos y lo primero que es destruido son precisamente las variables estaticas**.

Para esto sobreecribe los métodos de tu `Activity`, `onPause()` para guardar el valor y `onResume()` donde obtendrás el valor guardado.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    //Guarda valor de variable cont.
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
     editor.putInt("contador", cont);
     editor.apply();

    }


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    //Obtiene valor guardado para la variable cont.
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",  Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    cont = prefs.getInt("contador", 0);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

La única solución fiable es llevar un contador en SharedPreferences. Opcionalmente, si quieres que este contador vuelva a 0 con cada inicio de la aplicación entonces puedes resetearlo en el onCreate() de tu clase app, la cual generalmente deberá extender MultiDexApplication. El aspecto de la clase Application principal podría ser el siguiente:

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {
    public static MyApp sInstance = null;

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
        setMainActivityCounter(0); // TODO: borrar esta línea si no se debe resetear nunca
    }

    @SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
    public static void setMainActivityCounter(final int newValue) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getInstance().getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("MainActivityCounter", newValue);
        editor.commit();
    }

    // TODO: llamar desde cualquier lugar donde queramos consultar el contador
    public static int getMainActivityCounter() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getInstance().getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getInt("MainActivityCounter", 0);
    }

    // TODO: llamar desde MainActivity.onCreate()
    public static void increaseMainActivityCounter() {
        setMainActivityCounter(getMainActivityCounter() + 1);
    }
}
```